# busqueda en php

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

quiero hace un busqueda por cedula, y si se encuentra que me retoner a un editar pero si no se encuentra que me retorne el valor a un registrar pero no me retorna nada

aqui es donde hago la busqueda

```
< form action="" method="POST">

< label>Cedula</label>

< input text="number" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Introduzca su Cedula ej: 12345678 o 01234567" pattern="[0-9]{8}" maxlength="8" class="form-control" required>

    < input type="hidden" name="enviar" value="si">
    < input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info">

< /form>
```

El controlador

```
require_once('../modelo/modelobusqueda.php');

    $obj = new busqueda();
    if (isset($_POST['enviar']))
    {
        $value= $obj->busquedaexp();

    }
```

y aqui el modelo

```
require_once('conexion.php');

class busqueda
{

    private $conex;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conex = new conexion();
    }
    function busquedaexp()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT  id_exp, cedula, nombre, apellido, telefono, descripcion, direccion, fecha_nac, sexo, id_parroquia FROM `expediente` WHERE cedula = ?";
        $obj=$this->conex->prepare($sql);
        $obj->execute(array($_POST['cedula']));
        $value = $obj->fetch();
        if ($value) {
            return $value;
        }
        else {
            header('Location: vistaregistrarpersona.php');
        }
    }
}
```

si coloco un vardump si muestra los datos cuando si existe la cedula pero cuando no me muestra un array (size=0) empty

Comment: Y si dices `if(!empty($value)) {`?

Comment: Una pregunta importante ¿donde le estas pasando a tu modelo la cédula? Lo pregunto porque el hecho que hagas el incluye no indica que este recibiendo el post, ya verificarse que la cédula este llegando al modelo?

Comment: @alanfcm no me funciona cuando la cedula no existe

Comment: @CarlosQuintero lo resive con $_POST, si lo revise pero cuando quiero que redireccione cuando no existe no me funciona

Comment: @AnibalPeña el problema es que la redireccion la estas realizando desde el modelo y la deberías hacer desde el controlador, en vez de devolver el header, deberías devolver un **false** y validar la respuesta en tu controlador si el modelo retorna el false, que redireccione

Comment: por ejemplo en tu modelo: `return ($value) ? $value : false;` y en tu controlador: `if($value){ //loquesea que hagas }else{ //AQUI REDIRIGES SI ES FALSE }`